# Would Gorilla Glue Work on Goretex?

Tags: gear, boots, diy, repairs, waterproofing

Is this waterproof glue effective on Goretex? It mentions 'etceteras' in its label but does it stick Goretex to fabric?

[image: Gorilla Glue]

[image: Gorilla glue]

The stitching on my boot is ripped. I'm not considering sewing it because the needle would tear the Goretex. I know there are other waterproof glues available but I'm specifically interested in knowing if this one does the job. It's not somewhere under pressure I think; (the stitches are gone because of manufacturing fault but I didn't refund them because I wanted the boots!)

[image: the boot]

Comment: Better to stitch and seal it than glue it.  Glue will most likely be a temporary fix.

Comment: As implied by the comment from @mattnz the question is not if the glue will stick, the question should be how will it hold up under stress from flexing.

Comment: Spot on @JamesJenkins.  Gorilla (brand) glue is designed for static loading.  I have been able to remove it from plastic simply by lightly bending the plastic object.  I would go with a Goop (brand) glue for boots.

Comment: I didn't ask if it sticks, I asked if it's effective. :D thanks for the answer and comment anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [krazy glue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate) as long as the shoe is clean.

Do not cut the loose thread, but using a needle hide the thread between some fabric. Put the crazy glue along the entire section of stitching in order to reinforce the stitching itself.

This should work as I have done this on outside chairs and no one knows that I repaired them.

All said and done the best thing to do is restitch the shoe by hand using the same holes of the manufacturer and then glue it on both sides of the stitch (top and bottom).

Gorilla Glue might work but being a waterproof glue is not the same as being breathable such as your Goretex fabric in the shoe. It will form a barrier between the shoe and the rain or water. At least with the kazy glue it is possible to spot glue your shoe.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a good solution for foot wear.

While it will bond, it forms a waterproof bond that you can ["Sand, Paint or Stain".](http://www.gorillatough.com/gorilla-glue) It is great for many thing you might sand, but not for things that flex.